# Error en código al pedir por segunda vez una variable

Tags: java, excepciones

Al ingresar un valor en la variable **opción** para que entre al switch hace todo correctamente, pero al volver al while para pedir de nuevo la variable opción me salta la *excepción*. He probado también ha hacerlo con Scanner y cerrando el BufferedReader con el método close, pero nada(ya que los de los métodos se cierran con el try with resources). Porfavor si alguién encuentra una solución y me digas el error estaré muy agradecido.[El error me da cada vez que vuelvo a pedir el valor de opción para entrar de nuevo al switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1IrM.png)
Si encuentran algún otro error en el código agradecería que me lo muestren

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class Ejercicio6 {

    public static void cadena(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto");
            String cadena = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(cadena);
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error ");
        }
    }


    public static void caracter(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto");
            char letra = br.readLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(letra);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error ");
        }
    }


    public static void entero(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto");
            int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println(num);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error ");
        }
    }

    public static void leerShort(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto");
            Short num = Short.valueOf(br.readLine());
            System.out.println(num);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error ");
        }
    }

    public static void leerDouble(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto");
            Double num = Double.valueOf(br.readLine());
            System.out.println(num);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error ");
        }
    }

    public static void leerFloat(){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            System.out.println("Introduce una cadena de texto");
            Float num = Float.valueOf(br.readLine());
            System.out.println(num);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error ");
        }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String opcion;

        do {
            System.out.println("Menú \n" +
                    "-----\n" + "1. Leer una cadena de texto\n" +
                    "2. Leer un carácter\n" + "3. Leer un entero\n" +
                    "4. Leer un Short\n" + "5. Leer un Double\n" +
                    "6. Leer un Float\n" + "0. Salir");

            opcion = br.readLine();

            switch (opcion) {
                case "1":
                    cadena();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    caracter();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    entero();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    leerShort();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    leerDouble();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    leerFloat();
                    break;
                case "0":
                    System.out.println("Saliendo...");
                    break;


            }

        } while (opcion != "0");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: asi funciona el try con recursos, para resolver en tu caso particular debes eliminar el codio duplicado subiendolo al ambito superior(scope), de esta manera te aseguras que no se liberen los recursos antes de que acabes de usarlos. Intentalo y nos cuentas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo pondría "opcion" de tipo int. Si prefieres dejarlo como tipo String prueba a cambiar

while (opcion != "0");

por esto:

while (!"0".equals(opcion));

Comment: Eso no sirve de nada, es algo secundario.